# PyQt4 - QWidget save as image

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm trying to use Python to programmatically save a QWidget in PyQt4 as an image (any format would be fine -  PNG, PDF, JPEF, GIF...etc)

I thought this would be very straightforward, but I actually wasn't able to find anything on the web about it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

To be clear, I'm trying to do this

```
gui = <SOME QMainWindow>
gui.show()  # this displays the gui. it's useful, but what i need is to save the image
gui.save("image.png")    ## How do I do this?
```

Comment: I've never done this before, but maybe this question will lead you in the right direction (note this is Qt4 C++): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324409/rendering-qwidget-to-qimage-loses-alpha-channel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this using the `QPixmap.grabWindow()` method.

From the docs:

> Grabs the contents of the window window and makes a pixmap out of it.
>   Returns the pixmap.
>
> The arguments (x, y) specify the offset in the window, whereas (w, h)
>   specify the width and height of the area to be copied.
>
> If w is negative, the function copies everything to the right border
>   of the window. If h is negative, the function copies everything to the
>   bottom of the window.
>
> Note that grabWindow() grabs pixels from the screen, not from the
>   window. If there is another window partially or entirely over the one
>   you grab, you get pixels from the overlying window, too.
>
> Note also that the mouse cursor is generally not grabbed.
>
> The reason we use a window identifier and not a QWidget is to enable
>   grabbing of windows that are not part of the application, window
>   system frames, and so on.
>
> Warning: Grabbing an area outside the screen is not safe in general.
>   This depends on the underlying window system.
>
> Warning: X11 only: If window is not the same depth as the root window
>   and another window partially or entirely obscures the one you grab,
>   you will not get pixels from the overlying window. The contests of the
>   obscured areas in the pixmap are undefined and uninitialized.

Sample code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

filename = 'Screenshot.jpg'
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QWidget()
widget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
label = QLabel()
widget.layout().addWidget(label)

def take_screenshot():
    p = QPixmap.grabWindow(widget.winId())
    p.save(filename, 'jpg')

widget.layout().addWidget(QPushButton('take screenshot', clicked=take_screenshot))

widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

This will produce a window that looks like this:

[image: Application UI]

When you click the button, it will create a file named `Screenshot.jpg` in the current directory. Said image will look like this (notice the window frame is missing):

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If anyone is looking for a Pyqt5 solution, look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51361674/is-there-a-way-to-take-screenshot-of-a-window-in-pyqt5-or-qt5/)