# Is there a way to take screenshot of a window in pyqt5 or qt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
screen = QApplication.primaryScreen()
widget = QWidget()

screenshot = screen.grabWindow(0, 0, 0, 100, 100)
screenshot.save('shot', 'jpg')
```

How can i use this to get a window? it only get a part of screen:

```
screenshot = screen.grabWindow( widget.winId() )
```

I need a crossplataform method..

Answer (score 6):

Ref: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#grabWindow

You say you require a screenshot of a window, therefore

```
screenshot = screen.grabWindow(0, 0, 0, 100, 100)
```

is not the appropriate call here, since it captures the entire screen, cropped according to the final 4 parameters. (the 100 parameters are width and height).

```
screenshot = screen.grabWindow( widget.winId() )
```

captures the widget window. However, the reason you don't perhaps get what you expected on this call is that you don't create a solid widget and/or the widget hasn't been shown. Try the following example, making sure the app is on your primary display before clicking the button.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QtWidgets.QWidget()

grab_btn=QtWidgets.QPushButton('Grab Screen')
def click_handler():
    screen = QtWidgets.QApplication.primaryScreen()
    screenshot = screen.grabWindow( w.winId() )
    screenshot.save('shot.jpg', 'jpg')
    w.close()

grab_btn.clicked.connect(click_handler)

layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(grab_btn)
w.setLayout(layout)
w.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've tested this on Windows.

Comment: i try widget.winId() but its no getting a program(window) its getting the same primaryscreen but crop (im on linux)

Comment: What is the exact code that you use. Do you call screenshot = screen.grabWindow( widget.winId() ) without the int parameters?

Comment: I think perhaps the problem is that QWidget() is not a solid window. Let me check...

Comment: black image as print screen...

Answer (score 2):

If any one is coming here and having issues with the other answer, it might be a timing problem.

If you try to grab a screenshot directly during / after initializing the `QWidget()` instead of at the press of a button it might just make a screenshot of your desktop at the area of your window.

So if you want to grab a screenshot directly after calling `__init__`, call it after waiting some time with a `QTimer` (do not use `time.sleep()` as this would block the GUI).

```
def initUI(self): 
    (...)       
    QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.saveScreenshot)

def saveScreenshot(self):
    screen = QApplication.primaryScreen()
    screenshot = screen.grabWindow(self.winId() )
    screenshot.save('screenshot.png', 'png')
```