# Can't get a screenshot with PyQt5 on macOS Big Sur

Tags: python, pyqt5, screenshot

I'm trying to capture the screenshot of a window in my PyQt5 program using the `grabWindow()` method. I implemented the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51363003/13363688). It works fine on Windows but I always get a screenshot of my entire screen on macOS.

The code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QtWidgets.QWidget()

grab_btn=QtWidgets.QPushButton('Grab Screen')

def click_handler():
    screen = QtWidgets.QApplication.primaryScreen()
    screenshot = screen.grabWindow(w.winId())
    screenshot.save('shot.jpg', 'jpg')
    w.close()

grab_btn.clicked.connect(click_handler)

layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(grab_btn)
w.setLayout(layout)
w.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The result:
[image: shot.jpg]

Version info:

```
macOS: 11.4
Python: 3.8.5
PyQt5: 5.15.4
```

Is this a bug with PyQt5?

Comment: Try PySide2 and if you get the same result then the error is probably from Qt. In linux it works correctly.

Comment: @eyllanesc Nah.. PySide2 didn't work either. Same result.

Comment: So you have found a Qt bug, I recommend you report it. Maybe you could try with previous versions or with PyQt6