# Programmatically save PyQt Widget as image

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Trying to use python to programmatically save a PyQt5 QWidget as an image (any format)

Came across a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51361674/is-there-a-way-to-take-screenshot-of-a-window-in-pyqt5-or-qt5/), but this solution more or less saves a screenshot of the widget window, which demands the widget window to be open in the first place

What I'm trying to do is to get the widget to be saved without the GUI window being generated/shown on screen

So to be more precise:

1. Widget is created with script
2. Created widget is automatically saved without the UI popping up or external interactions

The widget I'm working with can be found [here](https://github.com/KhamisiKibet/QT-PyQt-PySide-Custom-Widgets/tree/main/examples/AnalogGaugeMeterWidget)

Comment: [`QWidget.render()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#render-1) (as also commented in [this interestingly closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74122483/2001654)).

Comment: oh okay, totally new to PyQt though, so still trying to figure out exactly how to utilize the function within the code itself.

Comment: Then try to understand how to use that `render()` function, as `grabWindow` obviously wouldn't work anyway: it takes a screenshot of the *screen*, how could it capture your widget that is **hidden**? Note: widgets that haven't been shown at least once *always* have a default size corresponding to 640x480 for top level widgets and 100x30 for child widgets (unless they set an explicit minimum dimension exceeding that size or a maximum one that is smaller than it). This means that you shall always explicitly call `resize()` with the required size (or with the `sizeHint()`) before rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I have found 2 ways to save a widget as an image (using PyQt6), not sure if they're the best or not but they both worked well enough (tested with widgets of type QPushButton, QLabel and QTableView).

First way:

```
imageVar = QImage(widgetName.size(), QImage.Format.Format_ARGB32)
widgetName.render(imageVar)
imageVar.save("imagename.png") #can use different file extension, a filepath or variable here instead if needed
```

Second way (which I feel is easier):

```
imageVar2 = widgetName.grab(widgetName.rect()) #returns QPixMap
imageVar2.save("imagefilename.png") #again any file name/path and image type possible here
```