# How to click an image from a live video in PyQt5?

Tags: python, qt, computer-vision, pyqt5, qthread

I am developing an application where a user can start a live feed from a camera. There will be a button when pressed will save the image from the live feed. There are also two button to start and stop the live feed.

I have developed the GUI in PyQt5.

[image: Application]
[image: AppWhenWeRun]

I used Qt Threads. The problem is I can start the live feed and also stop it successfully. But when I press the 'Take Snap' button, it is not saving the image.

How do I save the image from the Live Feed Video.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import cv2

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()

        # Set Main Vertical Layout
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

        # Make a Group Box
        self.groupbox = QGroupBox("Data Collector")
        self.groupbox.setCheckable(False)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.groupbox)

        # Create a Horizontal Layout in side the groupbox
        self.groupbox_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.groupbox.setLayout(self.groupbox_layout)

        # Create 2 Vertical Layouts in the Groupbox Layout
        self.button_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.feed_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.groupbox_layout.addLayout(self.button_layout)
        self.groupbox_layout.addLayout(self.feed_layout)

        # Add Buttons i.e. required functions
        self.add_Buttons()

        # Thread
        self.worker = Worker(0)
        self.worker1 = Worker(0)

        # Show Feed
        self.img = QLabel()
        self.img.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        self.feed_layout.addWidget(self.img)


    def add_Buttons(self):
        # Create 3 Horizontal Layouts
        self.hbox_3 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox_3.setSpacing(10)
        self.hbox_3.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)

        # Layout 5
        self.hbox_5 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox_5.setSpacing(10)
        self.hbox_5.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.hbox_5.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)

        self.hbox_6 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox_6.setSpacing(50)
        self.hbox_6.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)


        # Layout 3
        start_camera = QPushButton("Start Feed")
        stop_camera = QPushButton("Stop Feed")
        start_camera.setMaximumSize(200, 30)
        stop_camera.setMaximumSize(200, 30)
        start_camera.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        stop_camera.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        start_camera.clicked.connect(self.start_Feed)
        stop_camera.clicked.connect(self.stop_Feed)

        # Add widgets to Layout 3
        self.hbox_3.addWidget(start_camera)
        self.hbox_3.addWidget(stop_camera)
        self.button_layout.addLayout(self.hbox_3)


        # Layout 5
        self.take_picture = QPushButton("Take Snap")
        self.take_picture.setMaximumSize(200,30)
        self.take_picture.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        # self.take_picture.clicked.connect(self.take_Snap)

        # Add widgets to Layout 5
        self.hbox_5.addWidget(self.take_picture)
        self.button_layout.addLayout(self.hbox_5)

        # Layout 6
        self.clicked_image = QLabel()
        self.clicked_image.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)

        # Add widgets to Layout 6
        self.hbox_6.addWidget(self.clicked_image)
        self.button_layout.addLayout(self.hbox_6)

    def start_Feed(self):
        self.worker.start()
        self.worker.image_update.connect(self.image_Update_Slot)


    def image_Update_Slot(self, image):
        self.img.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
        if self.take_picture.isChecked() == True:
            image.save('1.png')
            print("DONE")

    # def take_Snap(self):
    #     self.worker.stop()
    #     self.worker1.start()
    #     self.worker1.image_update.connect(self.save_Image)
    #     self.worker1.stop()
    #     self.worker.start()
    #
    # def save_Image(self, image):
    #     print('**')
    #     image.save("1.png")

    def stop_Feed(self):
        self.worker.stop()


class Worker(QThread):
    image_update = pyqtSignal(QImage)
    def __init__(self, n):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.n = n
    def run(self):
        self.thread_active = True
        capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self.n, cv2.CAP_V4L)
        while self.thread_active:
            ret, frame = capture.read()
            if ret:
                img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                flipped_img = cv2.flip(img,1)
                to_qt = QImage(flipped_img.data, flipped_img.shape[1], flipped_img.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
                pic = to_qt.scaled(640, 480, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
                self.image_update.emit(pic)

    def stop(self):
        self.thread_active = False
        self.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    root = App()
    root.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to take screenshot of a window in pyqt5 or qt5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51361674/is-there-a-way-to-take-screenshot-of-a-window-in-pyqt5-or-qt5)

Comment: No. I want to take a picture from a camera feed. The camera might be a web cam or a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: The signal will send a *pointer* to the QImage, which will be immediately overwritten on the next iteration of the while-loop. This will usually either result in a crash, or a null/corrupted QPixamp. You need to send a [copy of the image](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#copy) (or the raw image data, as bytes). Also, note that you are connecting the signal *every time the button is pressed*, which will result in multiple calls to the same slot. You should instead make only one connection when the worker is created in `__init__`.

Comment: Could you please show that in code ?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I followed your advice and got the result.